# Why ClassGraph finds classes from other deployment on Wildfly?

Tags: classgraph

I prepared WAR archive and I deployed it on Wildfly 21.
I want to find all classes annotated with javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath annotation.

```
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph().enableAllInfo().whitelistPackages( PACKAGE ).scan())
        {
            final ClassInfoList classesWithAnnotation =
                    scanResult.getClassesWithAnnotation( ApplicationPath.class.getName() );
        }
```

It finds two classes, one from my deployment and one from other deployment. I undeployed other deployment to make sure that one class is taken from it and I am sure, if only one deployment is deployed on Wildfly then it return only one class.

I do not understand why ClassGraph finds classes from other deployment. How to configure ClassGraph to scan only deployment which ClassGraph itself belongs? I guess that I have to configure class loader, but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that there is no any configuration options that could meet my requirements. Source code modification is needed.

There is `JBossClassLoaderHandler#findClasspathOrder` method.
First `org.jboss.modules.Module` is retrieved from class loader. Next `getCallerModuleLoader` method is invoked and returns different class loader. Original class loader is an instance of `org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader` class. Class loader retrieved by `getCallerModuleLoader` method is an instance of `org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader` class. Next `moduleMap` method is invoked and returns map of modules. This map contains both my deployments. Next operations are executed for each map entry.

I also do not see possibility to add my own implementation of `nonapi.io.github.classgraph.classloaderhandler.ClassLoaderHandler` without source code modification because handlers are kept in unmodifiable final filed in `ClassLoaderHandlerRegistry` class.